# Using gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' , how to get scss extension for stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass

I want to have twitter bootstrap css framework in my RoR app.
In my gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

on my terminle I did:

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

All my stylesheet are with .less extension. But I want to \have .scss extension. How do I get this done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twitter-bootstrap-rails` works with less files.

If you want scss files you could work with the `bootstrap-sass` gem https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass